# Why this expression not following greedy approach?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-greedy

Why this expression is not following greedy approach?

```
string input = @"cool  man! your  dog can walk on water ";
string pattern = @"cool (?<cool>(.*))    (?<h>((dog)*)) (?(h)(?<dog>(.*))) ";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);


foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("cool=" + match.Groups["cool"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("dog=" + match.Groups["dog"].Value);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output:

```
cool=  man! your  dog can walk on water
dog=
```

As you can observe: 
(dog) group is matched 0 times.But since,* is greedy,why doesn’t it tries to find maximum matches of (dog) which is 1?

Any clues?

Answer (score 7):

The first `.*` initially matches the whole string.  Then the regex engine determines whether it needs to back off to match the rest of the regex. But `(?<h>((dog)*))` and  `(?(h)(?<dog>(.*)))` can both legally match zero characters, so no backtracking is needed (as far as the `.*` is concerned).  Try using a non-greedy `.*?` in that part.

**EDIT (in response to the additional info posted in the answer below):** Okay, replacing the first `.*` with a non-greedy `.*?` *does* have an effect, just not the one you want.  Where everything after the word "cool" was being captured in group `<cool>` before, now it's being captured in group `<dog>`.  Here's what's happening:

After the word "cool" is matched, `(?<cool>(.*?))` initially matches nothing (the opposite of the greedy behavior), and `(?<h>((dog)*))` tries to match.  This part *will always succeed* no matter where it's tried, because it can match either "dog" or an empty string.  That means the conditional expression in `(?(h)...)` will always evaluate to `true`, so it goes ahead and matches the rest of the input with `(?<dog>(.*))`.

As I understand it, you want to match everything after "cool" in named group `<cool>`, unless the string contains the word "dog"; then you want to capture everything after "dog" in named group `<dog>`.  You're trying to use a [conditional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) for that, but it's not really the right tool.  Just do this:

```
string pattern = @"cool (?<cool>.*?) (dog (?<dog>.*))?$";
```

The key here is the `$` at the end; it forces the non-greedy `.*?` to keep matching until it reaches the end of the string.  Because it's non-greedy, it tries to match the next part of the regex, `(dog (?<dog>.*))`, before consuming each character.  If the word "dog" is there, the rest of the string will be consumed by `(?<dog>.*)`; if not, the regex still succeeds because the `?` makes that whole part optional.

Answer (score 0):

I did tried  non-greedy `(.*?)` but it has no effect which is obvious as non-greedy `(.*?)` stands for `{0,1}`.and since even zero characters matches here,so no effect.

Any ideas how can correct it .I mean ,i want to capture the string followed by `(dog)` if its present there or else the previous group will capture the string `(cool(.*))`

The problem is that `(dog)` is optional and if its present,we need the string following it.

using `(dog)?` doesn't have any effect as it again matches zero characters.

Thanks .

Comment: I think you've got the wrong idea about non-greedy quantifiers; read this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html  For the rest, see my edit to my original answer.